# Django: send json response from view to a specific template

Tags: python, json, django

The main requirement is to send a json object from django view to a specific template named output.html (already present in templates directory), **as a part of response**. Also, the json response contains **model** and **pk** attribute, I want to remove them and send only the **fields** json attribute.

**When I try as follows :**

```
def view_personal_details (request):
  personal_detail_json = personal_details.objects.all()
  personal_detail = serializers.serialize('json', personal_detail_json)
  return HttpResponse (serializers.serialize('json', personal_detail_json), content_type='application/json');
```

I get json in a new page.

**And when I try as follows :**

```
def view_personal_details (request):
  personal_detail_json = personal_details.objects.all()
  personal_detail = serializers.serialize('json', personal_detail_json)
  return render (request, "webFiles/output.html", {'personal_detail': personal_detail})
```

I have to access the data via **{{ personal_detail }}** in my html, and not from response.

Also, the json response is as follows :

```
[
  {
    model: "buglockerApp.personal_details",
    pk: "001",
    fields: {
      name: "Rajiv Gupta",
      email: "rajiv@247-inc.com",
      doj: "2016-06-22",
      dob: "2016-06-22",
      address: "Bangalore",
      contact: "9909999999"
    }
  }
]
```

I don't want the **model** and **pk** to be sent as the response. Only **fields** should be sent as a part of response to webFiles/output.html file.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do the following in python2.7

```
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse

def view_personal_details (request):
    personal_detail = serializers.serialize('json', personal_details.objects.all())
    output = [d['fields'] for d in json.loads(personal_detail)]
    #  return render (request, "webFiles/output.html", {'personal_detail': output})
    #  for ajax response
    return JsonResponse({'personal_detail': output})
```

or you can read the following for more clarification 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/serialization/#serialization-of-natural-keys
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/serializers/base.py#L53

Comment: It is giving me the error "String indices must be integers"

Comment: Also, please suggest me the other part of the question i.e. send json response to a specific page, as HttpResponse sends it to a totally new page.

Comment: It worked. Now there is no model and pk element.
What about the response part? How can we send the json to a particular page as a part of http response?

Comment: I have a question regarding this:
Whether this personal_details in the last line is added as a response or not. And if yes, then how to fetch it in js using ajax?

Comment: @RajivGupta I have updated code for ajax response. please have a look.

Comment: How can we redirect this to a specific template?
I'm looking for a complete flow of "how to send json from view to a specific  template and fetch there using ajax".

Comment: @RajivGupta read this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/django_ajax.htm

Comment: Thanks @Anjaneyulu !! You are really a helping hand :)

I am fetching my data in react component.
If we send output like "return render (request, "webFiles/output.html", {'personal_detail': output})", we can directly access it using {{personal_detail}} in template.

But I've been struggling to pull it in react js component, and then send it  to html.

    Adding the react code below:

Comment: This is the actual requirement:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38936019/fetch-django-render-argument-in-react-js-component

Answer (score 0):

The default serializers always add the model and pk so that the data can be deserialized back into objects. Either you can write a custom serializer or can simply remove the unwanted data.

```
personal_details = [pd['fields'] for pd in personal_details]
```

This should give you a new list of dicts with personal details

Comment: It is giving me the error "String indices must be integers"

Comment: Also, please suggest me the other part of the question i.e. send json response to a specific page, as HttpResponse sends it to a totally new page.

Comment: Looks like Anjaneyulu has answered all this :) but if i had to answer, it would have been the same

Comment: You can help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38936019/fetch-django-render-argument-in-react-js-component