# Fetch django render argument in react js component

Tags: javascript, html, django, reactjs

I'm facing issues with passing the django render argument as a server response and fetch it using react component and then send it to html.

**Below is the Django code :**

```
def view_personal_details (request):
    personal_detail_json = personal_details.objects.all()
    personal_detail = serializers.serialize('json', personal_detail_json)
    return render (request, "webFiles/reactOutput.html", {'personal_detail': personal_detail})
```

**Following is the react code, to fetch the 'personal_detail' sent via django response :**

```
var categories = []; //{ "model": "buglockerApp.authentication_details", "pk": 1, "fields": { "userid": "001", "password": "rajiv@247", "sec_que": "Pet Name", "sec_ans": "Jerry" } }];

var App = _react2.default.createClass({
    displayName: 'App',

    getInitialState: function getInitialState() {
        return {
            data: null
        };
    },
    componentDidMount: function componentDidMount() {
        var self = this;
        //var http = require("http");
    var REQUEST_URL = "/viewPersonalDetails";
    // var request = http.get(REQUEST_URL, function (response) {
    //  console.log ("react response" + JSON.stringify(response));
    //  var buffer = "", 
    //         data;
    //     console.log("categories :" + JSON.stringify(categories));
    //  response.on("data", function (chunk) {
    //         buffer += chunk;
    //  }); 

    //  response.on("end", function (err) {
       //      self.setState({
       //          categories: buffer
       //      });
       //      console.log('buffer: ' + buffer);
    //      console.log('categories: ' + JSON.stringify(categories));
    //  }); 
    // });

    fetch(REQUEST_URL, {
          method: 'get',
          dataType: 'json',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        })
        .then((response) => 
          {
            return response.json() // << This is the problem
          })
        .then((responseData) => { // responseData = undefined

           return responseData;
         })
        .then((data) => { 

           console.log(data);
         });
    },
    render: function render() {
        return _react2.default.createElement(
            'div',
            null,
            _react2.default.createElement(_griddleReact2.default, { results: categories, tableClassName: 'table', showFilter: true, showSettings: true, columns: [] })
        );
    }
});

_reactDom2.default.render(_react2.default.createElement(App, null), document.getElementById('app'));
```

**Below is the HTML Content to which the react component will render the output :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
      <meta charset = "UTF-8">
      <title>React First App</title>
      {% load static  %}
    </head>
    <body>
      Django Direct Output: <br />
      {{ personal_detail }}
      ------------------------ <br />
      React Output: <br />
      <div id = "app"></div>
      <script src = "{% static 'js/reactResponseNoDefaultJson.js' %}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The **{{ personal_detail }}** part (in above HTML content) gives the correct json value directly from Django, but the below part in html (i.e. app div and the javascript below) is not returning the content from react. **reactResponseNoDefaultJson.js'** is the minified react js.

Comment: Is there absolutely no response? I feel there should be markup. Do your console logs not print anything? I'm not an expert in react so can't say much about that code, but i'm guessing there is something wrong in your `componentDidMount()`

Comment: Neither do I have much react knowledge. That's y I'm facing this problem.

Comment: There is a response for sure. But "how to fetch it in react?" is the question...

Comment: Check this if it helps... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237200/fetch-response-json-gives-responsedata-undefined

Comment: Looks like it helped somehow, but still no output. Instead I started getting a Json Parse error on console log.


Image : [link](http://imgur.com/a/wsvuL) (the star is the react output).


When I directly print image, it's like this: [link](http://imgur.com/a/u1lN9)

Comment: your view doesn't return a JSON response, therefore the `response.json()` doesn't work for you

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not a JS hero but i think you need the django view to return a json  response to solve:

"// << This is the problem " line

check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) for json response object.